# Belkin Wireless G Plus Mimo Router needs reset every 2 or 3 hours

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, connection

Every 2 to 3 hours I have to unplug and plug in my router because my computers (3) lose internet connection as does my Blu-ray player.  I've tried resetting (paper clip in the hole) and it hasn't helped.  My home has nothing to do with it as it happened at my condo and is now also happening at my house.  If I wasn't bald, I'd be ripping my hair out!

Comment: please specify the exact model of the router and the firmware version

Answer (score 1):

You might not like this answer but I mean it sincerely and I think it is the best solution for your problem:

**Upgrade to a real 802.11n router.**

A company called Airgo made proprietary "MIMO G" chipsets years before the IEEE standardized MIMO as part of 802.11n. A few vendors including Belkin shipped products based on Airgo chips, but they were never very popular. Airgo was later bought by Qualcomm and, despite their lead in MIMO, somehow failed to become a player in 802.11n. At this point Airgo-based equipment is little more than a historical artifact, a strange proprietary ghost town in the wilderness between G and N. It joins the list of other failed oddities in the forgotten history of 802.11, such as channel-bonded 108 mbps "Super-G", Texas Instruments' 22mbps "PBCC" flavor of 802.11b, 152- and 256-bit WEP, Lucent proprietary 8mbps "turbo" 802.11, and the frequency hopping spread spectrum (FHSS) and diffuse infrared (DFIR) PHY types from 802.11-1997.

It doesn't surprise me that connecting modern Wi-Fi gear to a "MIMO G" AP crashes it within an hour or two, and that Belkin doesn't care to update the firmware for it (as if the former Airgo folks at Qualcomm would even bother developing updated drivers for Belkin to incorporate).

Time to modernize. Since you seem to like to stay on the same gear for many years instead of upgrading regularly, I suggest you buy something fully modern now to give you room to grow. So go buy a 2011 era simultaneous dual-band 450mbps (3x3, 3 spacial streams) 802.11n router like a current Apple AirPort Extreme or Time Capsule, or a Linksys E4200. Stay away from TrendNet; they have several models of 450mbps APs, but they're usually not simultaneous dual-band, and they're all crap.